# Android ToggleButton custom style not getting applied

Tags: android, android-listview, android-button

I followed [this example](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/) for applying some custom themes to my toggle buttons, but when I run my app I see the generic android toggle icons - I think I'm missing a setting here or there and could use an extra set of eyes on it.

I have a layout for use in a `ListView` for which I'm trying to use custom drawables for the checked/unchecked state, with each toggle status set to CHECKED by default:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/profile_item_value_text"
        style="@style/ProfileTagTheme"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:checked="true" />
```

Here's what I have in my `styles` file for `ProfileTagTheme`:

```
<style name="Widget.Button.Toggle" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/profile_btn_toggle_bg</item>
    <item name="android:disabledAlpha">@android:attr/disabledAlpha</item>
</style>
<style name="ProfileTagTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/Widget.Button.Toggle</item>
</style>
```

And in turn, `profile_btn_toggle_bg.xml`, living in my main `drawable` dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@drawable/profile_btn_toggle"/>
</layer-list>
```

which references `profile_btn_toggle`, right next to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tag_active" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tag" /> <!-- default/unchecked -->
</selector>
```

I've verified the custom images are present in the drawables dir, so obviously either I'm misunderstanding something about the way the styles cascade, or I'm missing a reference somewhere in this style madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems the only real problem I had was missing the `android:background` element in my `ToggleButton` implementation; so the only change to the code above was adding that element, e.g.

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/profile_item_value_text"
        style="@style/ProfileTagTheme"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_btn_toggle_bg"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="onToggleClicked" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this a few of my apps. keep in mind this is an entirely different approach to the styles and may/may not work for your situation. By setting the background I can set the image I want for my toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tb_useNotificationShortcuts"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/togglebutton"
    android:tag="21" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
   <!-- pressed -->
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/custom_toggle_off"/>
   <!-- default/unchecked -->

</selector>
```

The custom_toggle_on and custom_toggle_off are my images, these could also be your layer-lists.