# Android switch - change background of switch at on / off

Tags: android, xml

does someone know how I can implement a switch like this in my application?
[image]

or how I change the backgroundcolor of standard switch on switching on/off?

Comment: By setting the background when the switch is toggled. You can even add an animation to make it look nice! Glad to have helped you....

Comment: Do you want the slide toggle or the code of change background?

Comment: You can change it in the function `onCheckedChanged`. Here is [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) for you. And you can use `selector` in android to change background.
Here is [link](http://chandelashwini.blogspot.com/2012/10/change-background-of-android.html) for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ToggleButton custom style not getting applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735870/android-togglebutton-custom-style-not-getting-applied)

Comment: I think dev.bmax 's answer should be accepted one

Answer (score 33):

Here is sample XML for you to start off with:

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector"
    android:switchMinWidth="75dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector" />
```

switch_track_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_on"
        android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_off"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

switch_track_on.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />
    <size
        android:width="75dp"
        android:height="25dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#3E98F3" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

switch_track_off.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />
    <size
        android:width="75dp"
        android:height="25dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

switch_thumb_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb"
        android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb"
        android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

switch_thumb.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:width="25dp"
        android:height="25dp" />

    <solid
        android:color="#CCCCCC" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Saved my day. Just a suggestion: the toggle button looks much better with no borders (0dp), so maybe in the example have widths as 0dp instead of 1.

Comment: This is perfect answer which save your day and time without any extra efforts

Comment: Don't know why this was not selected as answer.

Comment: awesome, rarely seen better answer than this. But doesn't look that great for older API versions, so I added in values-21 for newer versions only