# how to customize switch in android?

Tags: android, switchcompat

I want to customize switch as shown in below image.

[image: Custom switch]

I have tried 'SwitchCompat' but can't customize it as image. Below is code.

```
<style name="CustomSwitchStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <!-- Active thumb color & Active track color(30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Inactive track color(30% transparency) -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

I have also tried with 'Switch' widget but still it dosen't looks like the required custom switch.

Comment: Have you tried it to change progrmatically ?

Comment: @jaydroider: can u guide me with some sample code?

Comment: Check my answer below. i am using it in one of my app.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28981942/4283005

Answer (score 1):

**Try to change it Programatically.**

**Refer this.**

```
public void switchBind(DetailItem item) {
    switchColor(item.toggle);
    listSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                switchColor(b);
        }
    });
}

private void switchColor(boolean checked) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        listSwitch.getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(checked ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        listSwitch.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(!checked ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

**Another way change color.**

```
private void switchColor(boolean isChecked) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        int thumbColor;
        int trackColor;

        if(isChecked) {
            thumbColor = Color.argb(255, 253, 153, 0);
            trackColor = thumbColor;
        } else {
            thumbColor = Color.argb(255, 236, 236, 236);
            trackColor = Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        try {
            getThumbDrawable().setColorFilter(thumbColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(trackColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note :** Change color as you want.

Comment: I'll take a look at it

Comment: the track color appears faint when I activate the switch. eg: I'm changing track color to RED when switch is active but it appears in pink.

Comment: any style is added to switch then remove it.

Comment: Try to get color using resources. defined with hax code in color.xml.

Comment: try edited part . first part is working for me. but as you have problem with it. try and check edited function.

Comment: Also check  and change build sdk version to kitkat infirst part  and try.

Comment: Brother i don't be able to assume now. may be this will help check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981164/android-switch-change-background-of-switch-at-on-off

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111534/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-kevz).

Comment: It helped me to customize switch to some extent. Tnx a lot :)

Comment: it will give you exact  you want may be some changes in my code to get it bro.